# How to put a sequential number in the middle of my filenames in Linux

Tags: linux, sequence, rename

I have some files in a directory and I want to rename them in such a way they will have sequence.

Original Filenames:

```
Customer_Branch_Record.20230303.1349.DAT
Customer_Branch_Record.20230303.1356.DAT
Customer_Branch_Record.20230303.1527.DAT
```

I want to put a sequence 01 02 03 and so on in between the filenames and output below

```
Customer_Branch_Record.01.20230303.1349.DAT
Customer_Branch_Record.02.20230303.1356.DAT
Customer_Branch_Record.03.20230303.1527.DAT
```

I tried Bash to rename but it can only rename into a new name and does not use the original details

```
#!/bin/bash

a=1
for i in Cust*; do
  new=$(printf "Customer_Document_Advices.%02d.txt" "$a") #04 pad to length of 2
  mv -i -- "$i" "$new"
  let a=a+1
done
```

OUTPUT:

```
Customer_Document_Advices.02.txt
Customer_Document_Advices.01.txt
Customer_Document_Advices.03.txt
```

I want to do this in such a way that I can place a sequence in the middle and still retain the original details of the filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try;

```
a=1
while read -r line; do
    echo mv $line $(sed -E "/(\.[^.]*){4,}/ ! s/[^.]*/&.$a/" <<< $line)
    let a+=1
done < <(find /path/to/directory -type f -name 'Cust*' -printf '%f\n')
```

If the output is as expected, remove the echo to persist the changes

Comment: Use more quotes...

Comment: `let` is 1980's style. Better use `(( ))`

Comment: mv Customer_Branch_Record.20230303.1349.DAT Customer_Branch_Record.1.20230303.1349.DAT
mv Customer_Branch_Record.20230303.1356.DAT Customer_Branch_Record.2.20230303.1356.DAT
mv Customer_Branch_Record.20230303.1527.DAT Customer_Branch_Record.3.20230303.1527.DAT
mv Customer_Branch_Record.20230303.1349.DAT Customer_Branch_Record.4.20230303.1349.DAT
mv Customer_Branch_Record.20230303.1356.DAT Customer_Branch_Record.5.20230303.1356.DAT
mv Customer_Branch_Record.20230303.1527.DAT Customer_Branch_Record.6.20230303.1527.DAT

Answer (score 0):

Using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

```
$ rename 's/(\.\d{8})/"." . sprintf("%0.2d", ++$::c) . $1/e' ./Customer*
```

##### `ls -1`

```
Customer_Branch_Record.01.20230303.1349.DAT
Customer_Branch_Record.02.20230303.1356.DAT
Customer_Branch_Record.03.20230303.1527.DAT
```

Comment: It did not work unfortunately, nothing happened to the file after running the command.

Comment: What is the output of `rename version` ? Which OS do you run?

Comment: NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.9 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.9"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.9 (Maipo)"

Comment: You need to install with `cpan File::Rename`

Comment: I cant install unfortunately :(, any other options maybe

Comment: You can just download it [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sputnick-dev/perl-rename/master/rename) you just need Perl as dependencies

Comment: Or if you can't download, **copy/paste** in a `rename` script...